# 2012 Chevy Malibu ignition switch

Tags: ignition

I bought a used ignition Switch and got it put on. Do i still have to program that? Or it should work because it was programmed before?  I need help

Answer (score 1):

If you replaced the key and/or immobilizer ecu that is attached to the ignition housing then yes, The immobilizer system needs to be programmed. If you bought an un-coded ignition lock cylinder and matched it to your original key and replaced only this lock cylinder into your original housing then no, you should be good.